# How to link in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linker

I have just started learning Python.

```
placemarker = 1
while True:
    print ("Welcome")
    command = input ("Enter command: ")
    if command == register:
        placemarker = 20

if placemarker == 20:
    registerMe = input ("What is your name? ")
```

I am trying to link to the placemarker 20 area when register is put into the input. How could I achieve this? Thanks, and Im just a beginner. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I have **absolutely no idea** what you mean. I think you might want to read through a basic tutorial on the language, though.

Comment: You mean you want to check if the user entered the string `register`? Or entered something that is equal stored in the *variable* `register`?

Comment: entered the string register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
placemarker = 1
while True:
    print ("Welcome")
    command = input ("Enter command: ")
    if command == "register": #String variable here
        placemarker = 20

if placemarker == 20:
    registerMe = input ("What is your name? ")
```

Change it like this, you should tell to Python it's a string, because `input` storing variables as string. Also you can write that like this-clear than your codes;

```
while True:
    print ("Welcome")
    command = input ("Enter command: ")
    if command == "register": #String variable here
        registerMe = input ("What is your name? ")
        print (registerMe) #print or do whatever you want on here
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `input()` returns a `String` so in the `if` statement you will have to change the `register` word to `"register"` because the variable `command` will be a string: therefore the if statement is looking for a String after the `==`. ***Hope This Helps***

Comment: That was a bit stupid of me, because I did know that